# how do you make images invisible onDrop android?

Tags: android, if-statement, drag-and-drop

hello and merry christmas to all, this will be my third question on this subject, (im very new to android) but ive made an app and in it there is a drag and drop shape game, it all works (kinda) there are 6 images, 3 are static dragListeners and three are onTouchListeners you can move an image and it disappears, id like to have the image only disappear if it is dragged onto its corresponding image and snap back to its original position if it is not, im sure its a case of adding more to my if block to say the image (square) should only be invisible when it is paired with the same shape (blank square) although im not sure where to throw it in and i also think i need to change the from.removeView call but im unsure again as to what to replace it for please any and all help greatly appreciated.

DragandDrop.java

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.DragEvent;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.DragShadowBuilder;
import android.view.View.OnDragListener;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.app.Activity;

public class DragandDrop extends Activity implements OnTouchListener, OnDragListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.draganddrop);
    findViewById(R.id.squareImage).setOnTouchListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.circleImage).setOnTouchListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.triangleImage).setOnTouchListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.squareImage1).setOnDragListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.circleImage1).setOnDragListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.triangleImage1).setOnDragListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {
    if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(v);
        v.startDrag(null, shadowBuilder, v, 0);
        v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent e) {
    if (e.getAction()==DragEvent.ACTION_DROP) {
        View view = (View) e.getLocalState();
        if(view.getId()==R.id.squareImage && v.getId()==R.id.squareImage1)
        {
            ViewGroup from = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
            from.removeView(view);
            v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dragsquare1);
            return true;
        } else if(view.getId()==R.id.circleImage && v.getId()==R.id.circleImage1){
            ViewGroup from = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
            from.removeView(view);
            v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dragcircle1);
            return true;
        } else if(view.getId()==R.id.triangleImage && v.getId()==R.id.triangleImage1){
            ViewGroup from = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
            from.removeView(view);
            v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dragtriangle1);
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }

    }
return true;
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.reset:
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: So what exactly is wrong with your code

Comment: @clay at the moment the images disappear on touch I only want them to disappear when they are dropped on there corresponding image

Comment: Get rid of the line that says `v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);` in your `onTouch` method. Does that do what you want?

Comment: thank you this worked a charm would you like to post it as the answer and ill accept it thank you very much knew it was something trivial i was missing :-) thank you again and merry christmas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the line that says v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); in your onTouch method.
When you press down, it makes the view invisible.